# Show that $F_1\cap F_2/K$ is normal if $F_1/K$ and $F_2/K$ are normal.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I have to show that $F_1\cap F_2/K$ is normal if $F_1/K$ and $F_2/K$ are normal. What I know is that \begin{align*}Aut_K(F_1)&\longrightarrow Hom_K(F_1\cap F_2,K^{alg})\\ \rho&\longmapsto \rho|_{F_1\cap F_2}\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}Aut_K(F_2)&\longrightarrow Hom_K(F_1\cap F_2,K^{alg})\\ \rho&\longmapsto \rho|_{F_1\cap F_2}\end{align*}

are surjective. So let $\sigma\in Hom_K(F_1\cap F_2,K^{alg})$.

**Question) Since there is a $\rho\in Aut_K(F_1)$ s.t. $\rho|_{F_1\cap F_2}=\sigma $ can we conclude directely that $\rho|_{F_1\cap F_2}\in Aut_K(F_1\cap F_2)$ and thus that $\sigma \in Aut(K_1\cap K_2)$. Is it correct ?**

Comment: OK, now I see what you wanted, just extend $\sigma$ to a map from something that contains both $F_1$ and $F_2$ and use the hypotheses. See the added proof.

Comment: Why do you keep tagging the questions as *finite-fields*? AFAICT you are not assuming that any of the fields here $F_1,F_2,K$ are finite? $K^{alg}$ most certainly is not. Do you read the tag descriptions at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's recall what an algebraic normal extension $K \subset F$ is: it is an algebraic extension with the property that whenever an irreducible $P\in K[X]$ has a root in $F$, $P$ splits completely in $F[X]$. Equivalently, $F$ can be described as the union (possibly infinite) of all the roots of some family of polynomials in $K[X]$ lying in some algebraic closure of $K$. This family of course may be taken to consists only of irreducible polynomials.

Let now $F_1$ and $F_2$ irreducible. Let $\alpha \in F_1 \cap F_2$. Take $P_i$  an irreducible monic polynomial in $K[X]$ that has all the  roots in $F_i$ and moreover that has $\alpha$ as a root. Since $P_1$ and $P_2$ are irreducible in $K[X]$ and have a common root their gcd is not $1$. But their gcd is in $K[X]$ ( by Euclid) and it divides both $P_1$ and $P_2$. We conclude that $P_1 = P_2 = P$ and all the roots of $P$ are in $F_1 \cap F_2$.

${\bf Added:}$ I see that the OP wanted a proof that involves morphisms of fields over $K$.

We have $F_1$, $F_2$ contained in a common algebraic extension of $K$ so we may assume $F_1$, $F_2\subset \bar K^{a}$. The fact that some subextension $F/K$ of 
$\bar K^{a}/K$ is normal means: every map $F \to \bar K^{a}$ that is the identity on $K$ takes $F$ to itself. So now take $\phi$ mapping $F_1 \cap F_2$ to $\bar K^{a}$ and identity on $K$. Extend $\phi$ to an automorphism of $\bar K^{a}$. Since the $F_i$ are normal we have $\phi(F_i) \subset F_i$ and therefore $\phi(F_1 \cap F_2) \subset F_1 \cap F_2 $ ( in fact $=$). Therefore, $F_1 \cap F_2$ normal

The OP was on the right track, just needed to extend the automorphism all the way to something that contained $F_1 F_2$.

Comment: How do you prove equality assuming $\phi(F_1 \cap F_2) = F_1 \cap F_2$? In the finite case this is trivial, but in the non-finite case you really only have an inclusion unless you say something.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva: For normality it's not necessary to check that, but it's true nevertheless. If $ F/K$ is algebraic and $\phi$ maps $F$ to $F$ and fixes $K$ then $\phi$ maps $F$ onto $F$ : for $\phi$ will permute the roots in $F$ of any polynomial in $K[X]$ and $F$ is a union of such finite subsets.

Comment: Then you need to define normality this way, which is not what is done in the Wikipedia article... it seems sad that the definition of normality using embeddings alone is not sufficient to show that the equality I pointed out holds, i.e. we always need to refer to splitting fields and finite-dimensional vector spaces arguments.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva: I assume that the OP considered the extensions $F_i/K$ finite so in this case there are no worries.

Answer (score 2):

What is your definition of a normal extension? ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension#Normal_closure)
 for options.)

Suppose $\sigma : F_1 \cap F_2 \to K^{\mathrm{alg}}$ is a $K$-embedding. You apparently know that there exists $\rho \in \mathrm{Aut}(F_1)$ such that $\rho|_{F_1 \cap F_2} = \sigma$. In particular, $\sigma(F_1 \cap F_2) = \rho(F_1 \cap F_2) \subseteq F_1$. Using a similar argument on $F_2$, you conclude $\sigma(F_1 \cap F_2) \subseteq F_2$, hence $\sigma(F_1 \cap F_2) \subseteq F_1 \cap F_2$.

If $F_1$ or $F_2$ is finite over $K$, then so is $F_1 \cap F_2$, so you would be done using the dimension argument of $K$-vector spaces since $\sigma$ is injective and $K$-linear.

If anyone can think of an argument which does not require using the second definition of normality (as displayed in my link above) in the case where $[F_1 \cap F_2:K] = \infty$, I would be pleased. In this case, the only argument I have is that $F_1/K$ is normal, thus $F_1$ is the union of all the finite normal extensions $F_1'/K$ where $F_1' \subseteq F_1$ (this is because splitting fields are normal and normal extensions contains the splitting fields of each of their elements, and I am using the second definition to prove this straightforwardly).

Note that if you know the second definition, the proof of this statement becomes trivial. If a polynomial $p(X) \in (F_1 \cap F_2)[X]$ has a root in $F_1 \cap F_2$, then it has a root in $F_1$, hence all of its roots in $F_1$, and similarly for $F_2$. Thus $F_1 \cap F_2$ is normal.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a polynomial of $F_1\cap F_2$, suppose there exists $x\in F_1\cap F_2: P(x)=0$, since $F_i, i=1,2$ is normal, all the roots of $P$ are in $F_i$ so there are in $F_1\cap F_2$ which is henceforth normal. done.